# xcode swift 3 lock screen remote control not working?

Tags: swift, xcode, class

i am trying to catch play/stop/next/prev user action from lock screen when player is active and playing , for some how its not working .

inside class `MusicPlayerViewController: BaseViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

do {
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
     print("bb> Receiving remote control events\n")
 } catch {
     print("bb> Audio Session error.\n")
 }

let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MusicPlayerViewController.nextTrackCommandSelector))

}

func nextTrackCommandSelector()
{
  print("omg")
}
```

in the log i can see only

```
bb> Receiving remote control events
```

also inside `AppDelegate.swift` has

```
   override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {

        print("remote::")


        guard let event = event else {
            print("no event\n")
            return
        }
        guard event.type == UIEventType.remoteControl else {
            print("received other event type\n")
            return
        }
        switch event.subtype {
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPlay:
            print("received remote play\n")
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPause:
            print("received remote pause\n")
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            print("received toggle\n")
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlNextTrack:
            print("clicked next \n")
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPreviousTrack:
            print("clicked Prev \n")
        default:
            print("received \(event.subtype) which we did not process\n")
        }
    }
```

and capabilities

[image]

what did i miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution

for swift 3 i have to add this

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
     try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. You're using both the delegate style and MPRemoteCommandCenter style of remote event handling. Pick one, rather than both to see if they're conflicting. Apple recommends the MPRemoteCommandCenter style, but if you're supporting older iOS versions, you may need to stick with the delegate style.
2. If you do elect to use the delegate style, my recollection is that you must also become the first responder in order to begin receiving remote control events.
3. Regardless of which style of event handling you choose, you must play audio in your app to let the system know to route events to you. The lock screen (or audio control center) should have your app listed in the "Now Playing" area.